# Partial view was not found

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have two actions in a controller that are called via ajax:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Slider(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var imagem = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["SliderImage"];
    string path = Global.GetAppSetting("CaminhoImagensSlider");
    if(imagem != null && imagem.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        String caminho = Path.Combine(path, imagem.FileName);
        db.ImagensSlider.AddObject(new ImagensSlider()
        {
            Caminho = caminho
        });
        db.SaveChanges();
        Global.SalvarArquivo(caminho, imagem.InputStream);
    }
    SliderViewModel sliderViewModel = new SliderViewModel(caminhoImagensSlider);
    return PartialView("_ImagensSliderPartial", sliderViewModel.Imagens);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DeletaImagensSlider(int[] imagens)
{
    foreach(int id in imagens)
    {
        ImagensSlider imagemSlider = db.ImagensSlider.Where(i => i.IdImagem == id).Single();
        db.ImagensSlider.DeleteObject(imagemSlider);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    SliderViewModel sliderViewModel = new SliderViewModel(caminhoImagensSlider);
    return PartialView("_ImagensSliderPartial", sliderViewModel.Imagens);
}
```

The first action works fine, but the second (DeletaImagensSlider) does not work. Checking the Chrome console I found that error:

> The partial view '_ImagensSliderPartial' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>       ~/Views/Configuracoes/_ImagensSliderPartial.aspx
>       ~/Views/Configuracoes/_ImagensSliderPartial.ascx
>       ~/Views/Shared/_ImagensSliderPartial.aspx
>       ~/Views/Shared/_ImagensSliderPartial.ascx
>       ~/Views/Configuracoes/_ImagensSliderPartial.cshtml
>       ~/Views/Configuracoes/_ImagensSliderPartial.vbhtml
>       ~/Views/Shared/_ImagensSliderPartial.cshtml
>       ~/Views/Shared/_ImagensSliderPartial.vbhtml

**EDIT:**
JS

```
$("#formSlides").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var data = new FormData();
            var files = $("#imagem").get(0).files;
            if (files.length > 0) {
                data.append("SliderImage", files[0]);
            }

            $.ajax(this.action,
                {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    data: data,
                    success: function (result) {
                        $("#imagensContainer").html(result);
                    }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('change', '[type=checkbox]', function (e) {
            if (this.checked) {
                imagensChecadas += 1;
                imagens.push(this.id);
            }
            else {
                imagensChecadas -= 1;
                imagens.remove(this.id);
            }

            if (imagensChecadas > 0) {
                $("#btnDeleteImages").show();
            }
            else {
                $("#btnDeleteImages").hide();
            }
        });

        $("#btnDeleteImages").on("click", function () {
            if (confirm("Tem certeza que deseja deletar estas imagens?")) {
                $.ajax("/Configuracoes/DeletaImagensSlider", {
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: JSON.stringify(imagens),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (result) {                       
                        $("#imagensContainer").html(result);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Why is this view found in one action but not in the other?

Comment: How do you call it from js? the js is within same page?

Comment: is partialview is in the directory that list in the error that show to you? you might need to make the location more specific `yourpath/_ImagensSliderPartial` in your controller for the second method, your first method is success because you use `this.action`, and i believe it is wrap within an asp.net mvc form, which it will get the pregenerate form location by asp.net

Comment: The view is in Views/Shared directory. The second action is called succesfully (I see it by debugging). The problem is in the return statement.

Comment: yes, your js did not have any mistake, is the return value, the path need to be more specific, `return PartialView("yourpartialviewlocation/_ImagensSliderPartial", sliderViewModel.Imagens);`

Comment: I try this: return PartialView("~/Admin/Views/Shared/_ImagensSliderPartial.cshtml", sliderViewModel.Imagens);, but still not working...

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by puting the entire path: "~/Areas/Admin/Views/Shared/_ImagensSliderPartial.cshtml".
But I cant understand why it works in different ways in the two actions...